# Is there a way to test Elasticsearch mutate locally?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, gsub, logstash-grok

I have written as a grok mutate  as below to remove a particular pattern:

```
mutate {
        gsub => [ "message", "\nmytestpattern", "" ]
       }
```

But I am unable to test it locally without pushing the code to a logstash pipeline .
Is there a way we can test mutate functions locally to see if the gsub is working as expected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `Stack Management > Ingest Pipelines` feature of Kibana. From there, you can create a new pipeline, add a gsub processor with your desired configuration, and then rely on the feature "Test pipeline" to verify how the processor behaves with some sample documents you provide

[image: screenshot]